# How to connect AWS MSK from Spring Boot or from local system with IAM based authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, aws-msk

Let me tell you the procedure I followed to create MSK cluster.

Step-1 : Created VPC with 10.0.0.0/16.

Step-2 : Created two public-subnet with 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24.

Step-3 : Created Internet gateway and attached vpc to it.

Step-4 : Bound Internet Gateway to routeTable.

Step-5 : Created cluster with IAM role based authentication.

Step-6 : Turned On public access on cluster.

Followed this : [Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html)

At the end two public client urls generated for cluster with port number 9198.

I have added this into application.properties file

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
```

Also for adminClient,

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin admin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                kafkaURLConfiguration.getKafkaURL());
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,"SASL_SSL");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM,"AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS,"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler");
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }
```

This is the error.

```
2023-10-05 16:09:48.819  INFO 6151 --- [           main] o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
2023-10-05 16:09:48.828  WARN 6151 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : The configuration 'sasl.jaas.config' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2023-10-05 16:09:48.828  WARN 6151 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : The configuration 'sasl.client.callback.handler.class' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2023-10-05 16:09:48.828  INFO 6151 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.6.0
2023-10-05 16:09:48.828  INFO 6151 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
2023-10-05 16:09:48.829  INFO 6151 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1696502388828
2023-10-05 16:10:18.833  INFO 6151 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1696502418829, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1696502418930) timed out at 1696502418830 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.

2023-10-05 16:10:18.834 ERROR 6151 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics
```

Please help me to find solution.

Thank you.

Comment: The logs say it logged in with IAM, so there is a different network issue. Btw, you dont need to duplicate admin config between properties and a bean

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer . Btw it took so much time for configuration and at the end I gave up and go for self-managed kafka on ec2.

Comment: I'm sure Confluent Cloud or Aiven, or similar hosted offering would have been a better option for high availability

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for the infomation. I'll look into these.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the configuration that worked for me

Spring Boot Configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: msktls
  kafka:
    admin:
    security:
      protocol: SASL_SSl
    auto-create: true
    fail-fast: true
    ssl:
      trust-store-certificates: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        MIIEXjCCA0agAwIBAgITB3MSSkvL1E7HtTvq8ZSELToPoTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
        ADA5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGQW1hem9uMRkwFwYDVQQDExBBbWF6
        b24gUm9vdCBDQSAxMB4XDTIyMDgyMzIyMjUzMFoXDTMwMDgyMzIyMjUzMFowPDEL
        MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDzANBgNVBAoTBkFtYXpvbjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTQW1hem9uIFJT
        QSAyMDQ4IE0wMjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALtDGMZa
        qHneKei1by6+pUPPLljTB143Si6VpEWPc6mSkFhZb/6qrkZyoHlQLbDYnI2D7hD0
        sdzEqfnuAjIsuXQLG3A8TvX6V3oFNBFVe8NlLJHvBseKY88saLwufxkZVwk74g4n
        WlNMXzla9Y5F3wwRHwMVH443xGz6UtGSZSqQ94eFx5X7Tlqt8whi8qCaKdZ5rNak
        +r9nUThOeClqFd4oXych//Rc7Y0eX1KNWHYSI1Nk31mYgiK3JvH063g+K9tHA63Z
        eTgKgndlh+WI+zv7i44HepRZjA1FYwYZ9Vv/9UkC5Yz8/yU65fgjaE+wVHM4e/Yy
        C2osrPWE7gJ+dXMCAwEAAaOCAVowggFWMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwDgYD
        VR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAdBgNV
        HQ4EFgQUwDFSzVpQw4J8dHHOy+mc+XrrguIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUhBjMhTTsvAyU
        lC4IWZzHshBOCggwewYIKwYBBQUHAQEEbzBtMC8GCCsGAQUFBzABhiNodHRwOi8v
        b2NzcC5yb290Y2ExLmFtYXpvbnRydXN0LmNvbTA6BggrBgEFBQcwAoYuaHR0cDov
        L2NydC5yb290Y2ExLmFtYXpvbnRydXN0LmNvbS9yb290Y2ExLmNlcjA/BgNVHR8E
        ODA2MDSgMqAwhi5odHRwOi8vY3JsLnJvb3RjYTEuYW1hem9udHJ1c3QuY29tL3Jv
        b3RjYTEuY3JsMBMGA1UdIAQMMAowCAYGZ4EMAQIBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IB
        AQAtTi6Fs0Azfi+iwm7jrz+CSxHH+uHl7Law3MQSXVtR8RV53PtR6r/6gNpqlzdo
        Zq4FKbADi1v9Bun8RY8D51uedRfjsbeodizeBB8nXmeyD33Ep7VATj4ozcd31YFV
        fgRhvTSxNrrTlNpWkUk0m3BMPv8sg381HhA6uEYokE5q9uws/3YkKqRiEz3TsaWm
        JqIRZhMbgAfp7O7FUwFIb7UIspogZSKxPIWJpxiPo3TcBambbVtQOcNRWz5qCQdD
        slI2yayq0n2TXoHyNCLEH8rpsJRVILFsg0jc7BaFrMnF462+ajSehgj12IidNeRN
        4zl+EoNaWdpnWndvSpAEkq2P
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      trust-store-type: PEM
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM
        jaas:
          config: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
        client:
          callback:
            handler:
              class: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
    bootstrap-servers: b-2.dummymsk.dummy.c8.kafka.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-1.dummymsk.dummy.c8.kafka.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9098
```

Here, security group must be setup to ensure client application can reach MSK over 9098 port. For public access, this port is 9198
Clicking on client information in AWS MSK will provide bootstrap server to be used.
[image: Client Information for AWS MSK]
Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/port-info.html

The certificate here is public available Amazon RSA 2048 M02 (https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/Amazon-RSA-2048-M02.pem) which was used by MSK I created.